# pgAdmin4: Unable to connect to Amazon EC2 via SSH Tunnel

Tags: postgresql, ssh, amazon-ec2, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have Amazon EC2 instance running Ubuntu. I have installed and configured PostgreSQL.

Contents of the file `/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf`:

```
local  all     all                   md5
host   all      all    0.0.0.0/0     md5
```

Also in `postgresql.conf`
I have set `listen_addresses='*'`.

The test command below is successfully starting psql console.

`psql -U postgres testdb`

Now I am trying to connect pgAdmin4 from MacOS.
I have created a SSH tunnel with following command:

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/test.pem -fN -L 5433:localhost:5432 ubuntu@mytestdomain.com`

Now I have following details in pgAdmin:
[image]

When I save, I get this output:
Unable to connect to server: server closed the connection unexpectedly. This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.
[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution,

install pgadmin 4 into your system. and configure the below-added configurations. if the below configurations do not work then please check that DB user permissions on AWS. because of the restriction on IP level so it may not be able to access.

[image]